# Controls inside pop up are not loaded in coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

on clicking button,pop up is loaded but Controls inside the pop up are not loaded in coded ui automation.

Seeking for the solution from your suggestion

Comment: What's your popup? Maybe some code, video?

Comment: It's a div contraining another div with checkboxes. Problem is that div with checkboxes are not loaded.

Comment: Still waiting for the response

Comment: Inside the pop it's consists of bootstrap controls

Comment: I don't have experience with Coded UI to test web sites. I have it with WinForms. But, if you provide me with your markup so that I can run your site on my machine, I could test it. Probably, I'll find something.